# aMule crash with invalid_socket

Tags: 16.04, crash

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh install), and I am now unable to start aMule. It closes after that error message :

```
../src/unix/sockunix.cpp(143): assert "m_fd != INVALID_SOCKET" failed in OnReadWaiting(): invalid socket ready for reading?
```

I found [that page](http://forum.amule.org/index.php?topic=21325.0) on aMule forum where it is said this is a bug in aMule.

So when will this be fixed on Ubuntu 16.04 ?
Thanks.

PS : I set up a fresh VM with Ubuntu 16.04 and aMule was starting fine, no crash...

Comment: I installed Wine, then I copied eMule 0.50a (from Windows) into my Home dir and it works if you go to the eMule folder and right click on the emule.exe fíle and choose Open with Wine Windows Program e.t.c.